# Netbeans git can't checkout local branch - Conflicts during checkout

Tags: git, netbeans, repository, branch, local

Here is my problem:

1. I have cloned project from remote server (branches develop & master)
2. I checked out develop
3. after changes, commited & pushed to remote, everything is fine
4. pull from remote while still in develop
5. commit after pull
6. switch or checkout to new created branch Page from develop - won't checkout.
   says: "Conflict during checkout" There is a popup window that says "You have local modifications in your working copy that would result in a checkout conflict. You can try to merge, revert them or review them in the Versioning view" - Merge is disabled, i can only Revert, Cancel or Review.
7. trying Review, shows no changes.
8. Team -> Show Changes shows no changes
9. Team -> Diff --- i tried to diff:

   - Local changes --- HEAD (no changes)
   - Local changes --- develop (no changes)
   - Local changes --- Page (no changes)
   - Local changes --- origin/develop (no changes)
   - develop --- origin/develop (no changes)
   - Page --- develop (no changes)
10. After seeing no changes anywhere, tried to checkout Page again (still develop branch is selected as i was working in it) -- this is repeating step 6
11. choosing to Revert (hoping for just getting that Page branch checked out) -- returns Conflict error while checkout

**Here is a bit of log from git console:**

```
==[IDE]== 30-Jan-2015 10:20:19 Checkout...
git checkout Page-editor-switch
git reset HEAD
warning: Skipping checkout of a symbolic link:
/Library/WebServer/Documents/licklist.desktop/app/webroot/js/plugins
git clean -d /Library/WebServer/Documents/licklist.desktop/app/webroot/js/plugins/ ............
it checkout Page-editor-switch
==[IDE]== 30-Jan-2015 10:20:30 Checkout... finished.
==[IDE]== 30-Jan-2015 10:30:21 Checkout...
git checkout Page-editor-switch
==[IDE]== 30-Jan-2015 10:34:14 Checkout... finished.
```

And here is how my repository browser looks like after all of above actions performed

[image: Git Repository Browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by manually checking out branch through console:

```
git checkout Page-editor-switch
```

Changes can be seen in Netbeans without restart or any other action

[image]

After all I assume it's a Netbeans bug which doesn't allow to switch between branches or checkout branch at some circumstances, even while all conditions were completed.

Comment: I think I'm hitting this bug too.   Did you file a bug report I can vote on?  Is there a git console built-in to Netbeans or do I need to install a separate git client in order to fix this manually?    Note: in my case clicking on revert button does nothing and the dialog just re-appears so I'm in an endless loop.